# how to use class to catch error in Log4net?

Tags: class, log4net

I use Log4net to catch errors. I want to create class and use it to catch errors. I don't want to catch error through TRY CATCH. How can I do it

Comment: Can you give a pseudo code example of what you are talking about because I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Log4Net is supposed for logging facilities. And it could be used for logging exceptions.
But it cannot be used to catch exceptions.

If you want to log exceptions you need to use `try catch` then you can log caught exception via Log4Net.